# AndroidStudio Debug/Variable window shows null on the fields inited with `when`().thenReturn

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mockito, powermock

I have a code:

```js
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(A::class, B::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Mock
    lateinit var powerMockVariable:A
    @Test
    fun powerMockTest() {
        val bbb = mock(B::class.java)
        `when`(powerMockVariable.b).thenReturn(bbb)
        println("A: $powerMockVariable Ab:${powerMockVariable.b}")
    }
}
class B
class A{
     var b: B? = null
}
```

Stopping with a breakpoint on the println, Debug/Variable for `powerMockVariable.b` shows null, but in real it refers to the correct value(`bbb`), making "step over", will print not null value of `A.b`.

[image]

Making `A.b` - open, fix the problem.

The question is, how to fix this without opening fields?

Comment: Based on this link (https://antonioleiva.com/mockito-2-kotlin/) using a later version of Mocktio might solve your issue. Not sure whether this version is compatible with PowerMockito.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I tried receipt from the link, mockito do the same - Debug/Variable for closed field mocked by Mockito shows null, but in reality, it is not.